# Reference form parashara Samhita?

Tags: reference-request, samhita, parashara

सन्त्यक्तकिटिरूपोऽसौ मूको नामासुरस्तदा ।

कलावीशापकाराय कर्नाटे सम्भविष्यति ।

मधु नाम वहन्नेष व्याससूत्राणि केवलम् ।

द्वैतमार्गानुसारेण व्याख्यास्यति सुमूढधीः ॥  (पराशरसंहिता )

There was an evil-minded Rakshasa named MUka.  Having given up his wild boar
form, he was known as an asura named  MUka.  He will be born in the Kali age
with a view to work to the detriment of Lord Shiva he will be born in the
region of Karnataka.  He will bear the name ‘Madhu’,  will comment upon the
Brahmasutras in accordance with the dvaita system.

Plz tell reference for this sloka form parashara samhita